# Does railsapps (rails-devise-pundit) apps have multiple role support baked in?

Tags: pundit, railsapps

In a stock "rails-devise-pundit" application generated using "railsapps",
does it include support for adding multiple roles for users?

A can I make John Doe have a `:user` role plus an `:admin` role

Answer (score 0):

In the default "rails-devise-pundit" application, each user has only one role. However, you can create your own custom Pundit policies to accommodate multiple roles. See the Pundit documentation.